# General bibliography for the work of Grothendieck

Tags: reference-request

I'm reading the first volume of Scharlau's Grothendieck biography (eagerly anticipating the other two/three volumes) and the Grothendieck-Serre correspondence as part of a historical-philosophical side project. I find myself regularly digging up papers of his, and sometimes this can be difficult, especially when the reference he makes to the paper in one of the letters is a bit vague.

My question: are you aware of any (at least fairly) comprehensive Grothendieck bibliographies? i.e. could you point me in the direction of a nice listing of some large fraction of his work, preferably organized in some coherent way or other?

Comment: Math Sci Net and Google Scholar will help tremendously to this end.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Of course, this is true about getting a list. Getting a list organized in any coherent way at all is another matter. Even genuine chronological order is difficult in google scholar -- red herrings and typos can throw chronologies off rather dramatically.

Comment: https://agrothendieck.github.io/ here you can find the writings classified by years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extensive biblioraphy in *The Grothendieck Festschrift*, Volume I, Birkhäuser (December 22, 2006)

Comment: Thanks, Colin. I suppose I should probably have just emailed you directly about this some time ago.

Comment: http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/GrothBiblio.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can find here a collection of all the minor (in length) works by Grothendieck with links

[Works](https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/works.pdf)

Included partial transcriptions of unpublished works